# Change position of a box only on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to change the position of the search box but only on mobiles.. I tried  to put `id="search"` on the box that contains the `input` with:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 


    #search
    {
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
        width:90%;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    }


}
```

But doesn't seem to work. I want the search box just at the bottom of the header, but only on mobiles. Is this possible?

Comment: That's because your grid framework for `col-md-12` has relative positioning on it. So your search form will always position absolute, relative to it's relative parent container.

Comment: Thanks for response. May I try position:fixed? Or is there any way to do this?

Comment: `position: fixed;` should work. The problem you will face is if you scroll, unless you also fix your header.

Comment: I've removed the link of your site from your question. Bear in mind that we want questions here that will be helpful for future readers, but if a question relies on a link that will shortly be fixed, it will no longer make any sense as soon as you fix it. If you can therefore show the problem entirely in the question, that is ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At work we use JavaScript & jQuery to move an element on different screen sizes like so:

```
function moveMenu(){
    if($(window).width() < 767){
        // If the screen is less than 767, move the menu to mobile position 
        $('#menu-header').prependTo('#mobile-menu-wrapper');
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise, put it in the normal location
        $('#menu-header').prependTo('#header-menu-wrapper');
    }
}
```

Its important that if someone loads the page on a small screen, then resizes it to large that this function runs. So we also add these two bits to trigger it on page load and on page resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    moveMenu();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    moveMenu();
});
```

This method means you don't have to duplicate menus to 'reflow' the page.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add another search box in the Center-block
2. Hide this on desktop and show it on the

UPDATE: Position fixed will work but will not allow to use other elements

the code is something like this

```css
#search1 {
  display: block;
}
#search2 {
  display: none;
}
@media only [....] {
  #search1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #search2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to improve your answer. You have provided instructions but best that you also explain it with some code.

Comment: Something like @media only [....] {  #search1 { display:none; } #search2 { display:block; } } ?  Thanks!